# After updating PHP version 7.3 to 7.4, facing Warning: finfo::file(): Failed identify data 0:cannot read `(null)' in myfunction()

Tags: php, php-7.4

> Warning: finfo::file(): Failed identify data 0:cannot read `(null)' in myfunction()

Here is my code :

```
function myfunction($file) {
  $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $content_mime = $finfo->file($file->uri); 
}
```

we are getting mime type for PHP7.3 but not for PHP7.4
Only PHP version is different nothing else.

**NOTE**: I found some patch for PHP 7.4 bug at here : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79681 but I don't know how to use it.

Please help me on this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like `$file->uri` return `null`, have you debug it?

Comment: It looks like your problem is in the $file object, not in the FInfo class. How do you derive the $file object?

Comment: We have the same `$file->uri`  in both the cases, PHP 7.3 and 7.4 as shown in the screenshot [$file object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsbsh.png) @simone-rossaini @LSerni

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `buffer` function instead of `file` for finfo object.
Find the updated code below.

```
function myfunction($file) {
  $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
  $content_mime = finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($file->uri));
}
```

It works for me (for PHP 7.4) and working as expected.